# ClearCase Explorer Folder Pane Missing

Tags: windows, clearcase

In ClearCase explorer, the "Folder Pane" has gone missing, which is quite annoying when traversing views. I have made sure that View->Folder Pane is checked.

I've tried disabling all panes, re-enabling them, dragging each pane around to different places trying to see if there's something I can pull out to re-expand the folder pane, but nothing.

Any idea how to bring it back?

[image: This is what my explorer looks like at the moment. Notice there is no Folder Pane.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to drag some more, as [described here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/file-and-folder-names-are-missing-clearcase-explorer-folder-pane)

> The solution is to drag the column back out from the side, however, it HAS to be done from the "column heading" row in the pane, such as where the column headers "size", "modified", and "version" are displayed otherwise the pane to the left is resized.

But if this is not related to your issue (considering the all panel is missing), check the registry, [as in this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000003536815) and:

> Delete this registry key:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\ClearCase Explorer
> ```
>
> It will be recreated the next time you start ClearCase Explorer and
>   (hopefully) your toolbars will be back to normal.
>
> After reinstalling my backedup registry, I tried deleting certain keys one by one in ToolBar-Bar5 and got the "File" menu bar back!
>   But a key I deleted also deleted the Shortcut Toolbar.
>   That was easy to fix, I went Tools->Customize and created a new "Standard Toolbar". It appeared on my screen, then I tabbed over to "Command" and dragged the icons I needed back to the new "Standard Toolbar".

Comment: Registry edit cleanup did the trick. Thanks for cloning from the original source.

Comment: @englebart Great, glad this is still useful.